# Send javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage to a recipient with non-ASCII name?

Tags: java, email, unicode, header, mime

I am writing a piece of Java code that needs to send mail to users with non-ASCII names. I have figured out how to use UTF-8 for the body, subject line, and generic headers, but I am still stuck on the **recipients**.

Here's what I'd like in the "To:" field: `"ウィキペディアにようこそ" <foo@example.com>`. This lives (for our purposes today) in a String called `recip`.

- `msg.addRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, recip)` gives `"忙俾ェ▎S]" <foo@example.com>`
- `msg.addHeader("To", MimeUtility.encodeText(recip, "utf-8", "B"))` throws ``` AddressException: Local address contains control or whitespace in string ``=?utf-8?B?IuOCpuOCo+OCreODmuODh+OCo+OCouOBq+OCiOOBhuOBk+OBnSIgPA==?= =?utf-8?B?Zm9vQGV4YW1wbGUuY29tPg==?='' ```

How the heck am I supposed to send this message?

---

Here's how I handled the other components:

- Body HTML: `msg.setText(body, "UTF-8", "html");`
- Headers: `msg.addHeader(name, MimeUtility.encodeText(value, "utf-8", "B"));`
- Subject: `msg.setSubject(subject, "utf-8");`

Comment: related question and solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5650455/923560

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ugh, got it using a stupid hack:

```
/**
 * Parses addresses and re-encodes them in a way that won't cause {@link MimeMessage}
 * to freak out. This appears to be the only robust way of sending mail to recipients
 * with non-ASCII names. 
 * 
 * @param addresses  The usual comma-delimited list of email addresses.
 */
InternetAddress[] unicodifyAddresses(String addresses) throws AddressException {
    InternetAddress[] recips = InternetAddress.parse(addresses, false);
    for(int i=0; i<recips.length; i++) {
        try {
            recips[i] = new InternetAddress(recips[i].getAddress(), recips[i].getPersonal(), "utf-8");
        } catch(UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
            throw new RuntimeException("utf-8 not valid encoding?", uee);
        }
    }
    return recips;
}
```

I hope this is useful to somebody.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but this might help someone else.  I don't understand how that solution/hack could've done anything for the issue.

This line here would set the address for recips[0] :

```
InternetAddress[] recips = InternetAddress.parse(addresses, false);
```

and this constructor here changes nothing as the encoding applies to the personal name (which is null in this case) and not the address.

```
new InternetAddress(recips[i].getAddress(), recips[i].getPersonal(), "utf-8");
```

But something like this below would work provided the mail server can handle encoded recipients ! (which doesn't seem common at all yet....)

```
recip = MimeUtility.encodeText(recip, "utf-8", "B");
InternetAddress[] addressArray = InternetAddress.parse(recip , false);
msg.addRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressArray);
```

Comment: The personal name is exactly the part that the OP wants to be converted. So it shouldn't be null in that case and would be encoded by the extended constructor.

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to convert the recipients of a mail: If you are using `InternetAddress.toString()`, simply change it to `InternetAddress.toUnicodeString()`.

`InternetAddress.toString(message.getFrom())` = `=?iso-8859-3?Q?Alican_Bal=B9k?=`
`InternetAddress.toUnicodeString(message.getFrom())` = `"Alican Balık"`