# Unicode chars and Spring JavaMailSenderImpl, no unicode chars under Linux!

Tags: spring, unicode, jakarta-mail

I'm using Spring and JavaMailSenderImpl, a famous spring class to send emails. My emails contain a lot of unicode chars like èéàò or most notably the dreaded € symbol. My classes work fine when the run on windows. The emails sent are with all the chars (plain text, no html). If I install my app on a Linux virtual server, I'll get all ? instead of the special chars. Is it Spring, Java configuration or something else?

**Update**

Basically the architecture is this: there is a Spring Web Application and I use spring JavaMailSenderImpl to get the work done. This is the configuration in servlet-context:

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="${email.server}" />
    <property name="username" value="${email.server_user}"></property>
    <property name="password" value="${email.server_pass}"></property>
</bean>
```

I'm using the same host on windows and linux to send mail (that is not the same machine where the application runs on... It is just a standard mail service provider over SMTP).

The code I use to send the email is simply:

```
SimpleMailMessage msg = new SimpleMailMessage();
            msg.setTo(adminEmail);
            msg.setFrom(adminEmail);
            msg.setSubject(subject);
            msg.setText(message);
            mailSender.send(msg);
```

Even setting:

```
System.setProperty("mail.mime.charset", "utf8");
```

at application startup doesn't solve the situation. In fact, before I was getting ? instead of €, now I get �...

Comment: nor really an answer, but have you checked the `locale` of the your linux user? maybe it's using a LANG that does not support those chars

Comment: Can you show us the code where the `message` variable is initialised?

Comment: it's just a normal string... Anyway I am posting the solution.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I am posting the solution.

**First** make sure about the encoding of the source code (if there is inline text). In eclipse is the first screen if you choose project properties. Warning: if you change it later it will garble your text.

**Second** It is better to use MimeMailMessage so that you can specify the encoding, like this:

```
MimeMessage msg = mailSender.createMimeMessage();

        msg.addRecipient(RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(adminEmail));
        msg.addFrom(new InternetAddress[] { new InternetAddress(adminEmail) });

        msg.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");
        msg.setText(message, "UTF-8");  
        mailSender.send(msg);
```

**Third** make sure the system property `mail.mime.charset` is set to UTF-8, either from Java command or by code like this:

```
System.setProperty("mail.mime.charset", "utf8");
```

*Thanks to everybody that helped me sorting this out.*

Comment: it says I've got to wait 21 hours... huuuuuu

Comment: Been working on Windows and had similar problem. Title and content messed up characters. using MimeMessageHelper to set title and content was the cause, even if utf-8 encoding was set there. Switching to plain MimeMessage.setText and .setSubject with UTF-8 specification worked.

Comment: msg.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");
the second param doesn't exist any more, any new updates to fix this problem with the new version of the API

Comment: Thak you very much. You saved a lot of time for me.

Answer (score 21):

In my case, I resolved the encoding problem by specifying JavaMailSenderImpl's defaultEncoding:

```
mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
...
mailSender.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
```

I believe you can also set the value in bean configuration:

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    ...
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: That's right, setting the value in bean configuration works as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely to be when you translate between an array of bytes (e.g. reading from a file) and a `java.lang.String`. Can you give more detail on your application's architecture?

Comment: No, I'm not reading from any file. Text is in string constants in the source code, so it's UTF (I think...)...

Comment: Is it a Maven project? You need to specify the source encoding per http://maven.apache.org/general.html#encoding-warning. There's probably an equivalent for Ant.

Comment: I've been thinking of setting mail.mime.charset to UTF-8, would that be enough?

Comment: You need to give more information (edit your question) about your application's architecture, also can you post some of the code where you call JavaMailSenderImpl?