# Tomcat encoding issue with email

Tags: java, email, encoding, utf-8, tomcat7

I have a java webapp deployed on Windows Tomcat for which I have made all the changes for setting character encoding to UTF-8 and it's working fine for all request responses. But the issue is junk characters are appearing on email sent using the webapp.

What need to be done to resolve the issue?

Code for Email Service:

```
SimpleMailMessage msg = new SimpleMailMessage();
Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
model.put("userName", StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(name)));
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplate(velocityEngine, "vm/messages/create_user.vm", "utf-8", model, writer);
        msg.setText(writer.toString());
this.mailSender.send(msg);
```

Example of junk characters in mail:

> Hallo P?ajwal Thakare,
>
> Sie erhalten diese automatische E-Mail, da Sie das Zurücksetzen Ihres
>   Passworts angefordert haben.

Here P?ajwal should have been Pʁajwal in the mail

Comment: How are you creating your email? Show your code so we *might* be able to help you figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: @tak3shi writer is getting updated by the VelocityTemplate mergetemplate method

Comment: @tak3shi updated the question with example

Answer (score 0):

Replace SimpleMailMessage with MimeMessage. Now you can set UTF-8 character set.

```
MimeMessage msg = mailSender.createMimeMessage();

msg.addRecipient(RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(adminEmail));
msg.addFrom(new InternetAddress[] { new InternetAddress(adminEmail) });

msg.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");
msg.setText(message, "UTF-8");  
mailSender.send(msg);
```

for more information see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636255/unicode-chars-and-spring-javamailsenderimpl-no-unicode-chars-under-linux).